# PDO variable not capturing/passing value

Tags: pdo

This code works but it is one change short of proper PDO--I would need to change " $user_ID " in the where clause to " :user_ID ".

HOWEVER, when I do that, the code doesn't update the contributions by 3 (which is the goal of the code). But it does work and update contributions as long as I don't change $user_ID to :user_ID.

Can anyone see why and what I'm doing wrong from this?

```
$yesupdate = "UPDATE points SET contributions = contributions + 3 WHERE ID
= $user_ID";   
$stmt4 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt4->bindParam(':user_ID', $user_ID, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt4->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt4->bindParam(':approved', $e = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt4->bindParam(':position', $row2[0]['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                        
$stmt4->execute();
```

FYI, the above code is a second query that follows the below query:

```
$yesupdate = "UPDATE writing SET approved = :approved, position = :position
WHERE WID = :WID";
$stmt2 = $dbh->prepare($yesupdate);
$stmt2->bindParam(':WID', $yes_WID, PDO::PARAM_INT);        
$stmt2->bindParam(':approved', $e = Y, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt2->bindParam(':position', $row2[0]['position'], PDO::PARAM_INT);                                        
$stmt2->execute();
```

Comment: Are you showing us the entire sql statement? Why are you binding all of those params that don't exist in the displayed sql statement?

Comment: I just edited my original post to answer your question...

Comment: You don't need all those bindParam lines for `$stmt4`.  In fact, I'm surprised the code works at all.  Using `:user_id` in the `$yesupdate` query should work just fine.  What happens when you use it? Any errors? Does the contributions column chang at all?

Comment: Is it just a matter of me referencing the other variables WID, approved and position in the update points code, even though I don't need them. Or perhaps I should just remove WID, approved and position for the update points, although that shouldn't keep the code from working

Comment: No errors if I use :user_id, but the code does not update the contributions column by 3 like it should. Nothing happens. If I change :$user_id to $user_id, then it works, but that is not PDO

Comment: Is $user_ID an integer or is it a string?  Are you using `:user_ID` or `:$user_ID`.

Comment: GOT it! Just removing the WID, approved and position binds for the points update code did it. I guess since they weren't needed or references in the update. One last question...do I also need to bind contributions to be safe, or do I not bind that since it part of a set clause?

Comment: You only bind a parameter if you are passing a value to the query. Since contributions is a column, you don't bind to it.